# Magento 2.4 Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: magento2.4

I was trying to upgrade from magento 2.3.6 to 2.4.2.

Now I have an issue that any `php bin/magento` command is giving an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Interception\ConfigLoaderInterface in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php(136): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->__construct()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.ph in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

I tried things like clear cache, redis flushall, but nothing helps. Any way to fix this?

Comment: what php version you are using? please switch to 7.4 if not yet switched

Comment: usign PHP 7.4.20

Comment: have you tried clearing the `generated/code` folder?

Comment: Had the exact same issue, tried all the above. I realized it was most likely stubborn OPCACHE. If you're smarter than me, you can figure out a way to flush that. I find that rebooting the server is the quickest way to get it done.

Answer (score 9):

Check your `app/etc/di.xml`.

I had the same error and it looked like the absence of this line:

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Interception\ConfigLoaderInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator" />
```

At the bottom of the preferences block. This was what was causing the Fatal Error message in my case.

However, the best thing to do is merge your di.xml with the [2.4 release di.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/etc/di.xml).

I know it's been 7 months since you asked this question, so I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

What solved this for me was regenerating composer:

```
rm -rf vendor/*
composer clearcache
composer install
then compile magento (setup upgrade.... cache flush)
```

Comment: Happy to hear you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

I just ran the "composer install" command and got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest solution for me was to remove vendor, run composer update and then setup:upgrade. Resolved issue within 2 minutes

```
rm -fr vendor
composer update
setup:upgrade
```